# Certificate error on company PC - Works on private PC

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, ssl, certificate

We are using a 3rd party webservice but we want to access their website with and other webb address.
But the problem when we access that site from our company computer we often get a certificate error message (please see the attached screenshots) and sometimes it works, rarely.

It works fine for the 3rd party company and so far on my private PC at home.

We are still on Windows 7 with IE 11, Chrome (v.60) and Firefox (v.55) and at home I run Windows 10.

Troubleshoot so far:

- We don't have any local DNS cache on our PC and I've cleared the cache on our DNS servers but it didn't help.
- Cleared cookies and reset IE, Chrome & Firefox
- Updated W7 & DNS-servers to the latest patches

Error messages

[image: Chrome]
[image: Firefox]

Comment: Simplest solution: Install the certificate for the certificate store on the work pc and Firefox the certificate itself clearly isn't 100% correct due to the error you are getting but doesn't mean it can't be trusted

Comment: It unusual for a certificate to be assigned to the root domain AND a wild card sub-domain at the same time

Comment: It would help to see both certificates: The one you get at home, and the one you get at work when it fails. It sounds like maybe they have the wrong certificate installed on one CDN node or one machine in a load-balanced pool.

Comment: @Spiff, Firefox says that the website don't supply the owner information ( https://1drv.ms/i/s!AolwST7Omf2r1xU7mWSrbuCspOro ) and that the requested domain dose not match the server's certificate ( https://1drv.ms/i/s!AolwST7Omf2r1xY1JWs1gKDVhT-C ).

Comment: @Spiff,
And in IE11 I can't see the certificate for some reason and in Chrome (v.60) it works in my Private profile but not in Guest, Work and Incognito-mode.
From Chrome:
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AolwST7Omf2r1xh6SEUNGfvn6rZm
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AolwST7Omf2r1xev734jixPA4AUj
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AolwST7Omf2r1xnJUrvR_PtVbaaU

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I don't need to see screenshots of various browsers error messages, I was hoping you might be able to capture and post the actual certificate binary data (maybe base64 encoded as typical) so I can run my own tools to compare the "working" and "failing" certs.

Comment: @Spiff,
Ah okay :)
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AolwST7Omf2r1x7VBqaPczqXy2Fw
I tried to PM you but didn't see how I can do that

Comment: @MrPew Those are two different certs, and the domain name you're interested in is only in one of them. So now you can show these two certs to this provider and ask why some of their servers are serving the cert that doesn't contain the name and thus doesn't work. Like I said previously, they may have failed to update the certs in some of their servers.

Comment: @Spiff,
That's strange. I got those via Chrome, I just saved it the two different format but I'll check with the providor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that our local DNS-servers had an old DNS record that made this strange behavior.
I removed some old DNS records to our 3rd party (Freshdesk) and it worked ever since.

I thank you all for your support in this!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Aha! Well, looks like the [SSL certs setup](https://support.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/90479) is part of the service that they offer, as long as you're on a [good enough plan](https://freshdesk.com/helpdesk-features).

---

In our company, we had some cases where we had websites set up to use an official cert for external traffic (public) and then, for internal users, a different DNS address. In this case, the server was set up to serve those internal requests using a self-signed certificate. This worked because we were able to acquire those certificates and add them to Firefox/Chrome so they would be trusted.

In your case, you are trying to access the site under a different DNS name in a similar way, but you're still getting the same certificate. The domains listed on certificate *will not match, ever* and you cannot override that. You would either have to...

- ask Freshdesk to add your custom domain to their cert and get a new one (which they're unlikely to do since it would cost them money)
- ask Freshdesk to detect when your requests come through on helpdesk.****.se and use a different cert such as a self-signed one (also unlikely because it may require major configuration changes on their end)
- get your IT team to set up a MITM proxy so that internal requests to helpdesk.****.se get translated into whatever DNS for freshdesk.com transparently, then re-sign it using a company certificate. This is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

First:
This is what they have already done and I've made the CNAME records on out local DNS-servers and on our external DNS (3rd party).

Comment: Second:
I'll ask them to do that if it isn't solved soon.

Comment: Third:
I would like to avoid using a proxy for a few reasons and one of them is that we don't use one to day.

Comment: Right! I didn't look at the actual service provider's website before, but it looks like they can accommodate that kind of thing. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned company PC and most of the companies have a domain controller.

I was also encountered with the same problem and it got rectified by removing PC out of the domain.

Follow below steps once if other solutions aren't working at times.

1. Make a desktop profile as an admin and change the password if you
   are using LDAP.
2. Login into desktop admin profile and remove the PC from the domain.
3. After the PC/Laptop restarts, adjust the data & time accordingly and
   perform a test.

Comment: There's nothing preventing a domain member workstation from being able to work in the same way a non domain computer in respect to this question about certificates. Removing a computer front the domain is certain to create many more problems that it would solve.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator. agree on that.. but solutions are differe based on the setup..